# How do I bind a radio button value to my model? Laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel-5

I have a form with a couple of radio buttons;

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('procurement') ? ' has-error' : '' }} col-md-6">
<label for="procurement" class="col-md-6 control-label">Procurement Type <span class="red">*</span></label><br>

<div class="col-md-12">
    <input id="procurement" type="radio" name="procurement" value="owned"> Owned
    <input id="procurement" type="radio" name="procurement" value="rental"> Rental

    @if ($errors->has('procurement'))
        <span class="help-block">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('procurement') }}</strong>
        </span>
    @endif
</div>
```

I am reusing the form for editing purposes so I want to be able to bind the object's value for 'procurement' when I present the form in edit view.  I am able to use this bind the values for text inputs;

```
value="{{ isset($vehicle->model) ? $vehicle->model : old('model') }}"
```

But this does not work for radios or selects.  What should I be doing?  I am NOT using the Form facade for this.

Thanks!

Comment: `old('model') === "owned" || $vehicle->model === 'owned' ? 'selected' : ''`? Add at the end of the element, after all attributes. This will select the `option` in a `select` list [see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) which I think is what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Not sure I fully understand how to implement that. Do you mean to add that into the value attribute or in an attribute on its own?  I tried this with no luck -     value="{{ isset($vehicle->procurement) ? $vehicle->procurement : old('procurement') === "owned" || $vehicle->procurement === 'owned' ? 'selected' : '' }}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `selected` and `checked` for what you want to do. Just add it to the end of the element, and it will select/check the element.

Something like this for `input` type `radio`:

```
<input id="procurement" type="radio" name="procurement" value="owned" {{ old('model') === "owned" ? 'checked' : (isset($vehicle->model) && $vehicle->model === 'owned' ? 'checked' : '') }}> Owned
<input id="procurement" type="radio" name="procurement" value="rental" {{ old('model') === "owned" ? 'checked' : (isset($vehicle->model) && $vehicle->model === 'rental' ? 'checked' : '') }}> Rental
```

And this for `select` options:

```
<option value="something" {{ old('model') === "something" ? 'selected' : (isset($vehicle->model) && $vehicle->model === 'owned' ? 'selected: '')}}>Something</option>
```

**Side note**: I'd recommend making sure that `old('something')` comes before other possible values when you're filling values in. For instance, you had:

```
value="{{ isset($vehicle->model) ? $vehicle->model : old('model') }}"
```

which would override the user's original input with database results (if any, of course) upon a failed submission. So if I was say, updating my name in a text field, and there were errors to the form, it would direct me back to the form and lose my input because the database results are before the `old` value. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Something is not closed in there.  Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/9f4NvFfuU1wymp9sFoNz?p=preview

Comment: @RushVan My answer was missing the blade syntax `{{ }}` but I've adjusted. Note that your plunker still has it in the `value` attribute and it shouldn't be. It should be _after_ all attributes in the element, right before it is closed.

Comment: Got it!  That works perfect if there is a $vehicle defined.  Now how do I add in the isset() condition so the form can be used with no model present?  Right now it's throwing an Undefined variable if I am not using for edit.

Comment: I've update to include a stacked ternary operator. It can be cumbersome to maintain if stacking too many, but this is still manageable. It checks for the old value, and if not located it then confirms the variable isset and exits if not. Otherwise it checks if the variable equals the value.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense but sadly, looks like there is a syntax error in there.

Comment: @RushVan It had `:` instead of `?`...fixed above. This sort of goes to my point that stacked ternary operators can be difficult to maintain haha :)

Comment: Zactly!  Sorry, I caught the error just as you posted it.  Thanks for the solve.

Comment: Hey Ben, I have a follow up scenario.  Do you have a couple mins to discuss?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126351/discussion-between-camelcase-and-rushvan).